# Statistical Model for multivariate timeseries

Tags: time-series, python, multivariate-analysis, statsmodels

I'm new to timeseries prediction and I would like to try several classical methods before getting into more complicated model.

Concretely, I have a multivariate timeseries of `552` datapoints. Each datapoint is a vector of `4223` entries.
I found in [statmodels](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/statespace.html#statespace) several multivariate models including VARMAX and Dynamic Factor. My questions are:

- Are they good models for multivariate timeseries forecasting?
- Are the better models? (not deep learning, please)
- Can I use SARIMAX model for multivariate forecasting?

I've tried the VARMAX model with my data but it doesn't work. Following is the code:

```
# vector moving average model (VMA)
mod = sm.tsa.VARMAX(x_train_no2, order=(0,2), error_cov_type='diagonal')
res = mod.fit(maxiter=1000, disp=False)
print(res.summary())

# # VARMA
# mod = sm.tsa.VARMAX(x_train_no2, order=(1,1), enforce_stationarity=False)
# res = mod.fit(maxiter=1000, disp=False)
# print(res.summary())
```

The fitting throws the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_varmax.py", line 62, in <module>
    res = mod.fit(maxiter=1000, disp=False)
  File "/home/tiendh/deeplearning_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/statespace/mlemodel.py", line 432, in fit
    start_params = self.start_params
  File "/home/tiendh/deeplearning_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/statsmodels/tsa/statespace/varmax.py", line 358, in start_params
    raise ValueError('Non-invertible starting moving-average'
ValueError: Non-invertible starting moving-average parameters found with `enforce_stationarity` set to True.
```

I tried to set `enforce_stationarity=False` but nothing changes.
One reason I can think about is the sparsity of my data. For one datapoint (4223 dimensions), there are just several values and the rest is zero, but I'm not sure. 
Could you please give some suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: "Can I use SARIMAX model for multivariate forecasting?" What exactly do you try to predict, 1 or 4223 values, and is it 1 step ahead or not?

Comment: It's one step ahead and there is only one target variable.

Comment: I wanted to advise you to use (S)ARIMA with external regressors, but the problem is that it needs the future external regressor values in order to predict. Try using VAR, it is exactly multivariate auto-regression. Are you interested in more details?